# Why does Postman with OAuth 2 Access Token return a HTML form from the request rather than the API result?

Tags: api, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman

I have quite a simple .NET Core Web API with an action that has been secured using Azure AD. It's quite a basic setup with a single action that returns some text. I'm able to verify that this is working correctly in the browser - if I'm not signed in when I attempt to access that action I am sent to a Microsoft online login page and when I enter in my login details correctly I am able to view the content, otherwise a 401 result is returned.

I've been trying to setup a GET request in Postman by using the Authorization tab. I set the type to be OAuth 2.0 and I filled out the Get New Access Token form with the information from Azure. When I click Request Token I am taken to the same sign in page that I get in the browser and I can see that Postman receives an Access Token. I can select that token and even verify that it is added in the Headers.

When I send the request, instead of receiving the data back from the API a HTML page is returned that contains a form with the callback path as the form action and the Access Token is shown in an  tag. I find this unexpected as I assumed Postman would have access to the API now. I also can't seem to find this issue anywhere else in tutorials and other posts.

I'm trying to find out what might be causing this issue and what steps I can take to try and figure out how I can send a request straight to the API.

Comment: Sounds like you have setup interactive user authentication on the API. You should instead setup JWT Bearer token authentication on the API so you can use it with tokens. An API should not work in a browser, redirecting to a login page.

Comment: That was it, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have setup interactive user authentication on the API.
You should instead setup JWT Bearer token authentication on the API so you can use it with tokens.

An API should not work in a browser, redirecting to a login page.
After all, it is used by applications, not a user using a browser.